# $(\mathbb{Z}/77 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong \mathbb{Z}/10 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z}$ - Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ a ring with unit element $1 \ne 0$ let $A^{\times}=\{a \in A: a$ invertible$\}$. Show that $(\mathbb{Z}/77 \mathbb{Z})^{\times} \cong  \mathbb{Z}/10 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/6 \mathbb{Z}$ as a group.

I am stucked on this problem for a while. Is anyone could help me at this point? or just a theorem allow me to conclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\Bbb Z/77\Bbb Z \cong \Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/\Bbb 7Z$ then

$$(\Bbb Z/77\Bbb Z)^\times \cong (\Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z)^\times \times (\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)^\times$$

Show that $(\Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z)^\times \cong \Bbb Z/10\Bbb Z$ amd $(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)^\times \cong \Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$. You can check that $[7]_{11}$ is a generator of $(\Bbb Z/11\Bbb Z)^\times$ and $[3]_7$ is a generator of $(\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z)^\times$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** When $p$ is a prime, we have that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z})$. Notice that $(\mathbb{Z}/77\mathbb{Z}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})\times (\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z})$.

Can you show that  $$(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times\times (\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong (\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/10 \mathbb{Z})$$

Comment: You probably mean $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times \cong \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$, but which result allow us to conclude? I think this is my main problem.

Comment: @Dr.Dray: Yup! Thanks for the catch

Comment: @Dr.Dray: This result isn't too bad for $p$ a prime. Notice that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field, and so the only non-unit is 0. That's why you lose 1 element.

Comment: Are you able to tell me what are the invariant factors here? I think the elementary divisors are $2^2$, $3$ and $5$.